# Remove some commits, but keep changes

Tags: git

What is the simplest way to get rid of few commits on a branch, but keep the changes ?

At this moment, when I run `git pull`, `rebase` is going on, but I don't have an option to choose, should I change my `git pull` strategy ?

Comment: When you say *"get rid of few commits on a branch, but keep the changes"*, I'm not sure what you're describing. Do you want those changes to be _squashed_ into other commits? Uncommitted in the working area?

Answer (score 0):

Say you want to "convert" the last 5 revisions into a single revision (or at least, get those changes introduced by them to be on your working tree as uncommitted):

```
git reset --soft HEAD~5
```

The branch (if you were working on a branch) will be set to point to HEAD~5 and all the changes between HEAD~5 and your current working tree will be put on the index so that you can commit them.